# Transfer learning with OpenNMT

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model, transfer-learning, opennmt

I'm training a transformer model with OpenNMT-py on MIDI music files, but results are poor because I only have access to a small dataset pertaining to the style I want to study. To help the model learn something useful, I would like to use a much larger dataset of other styles of music for a pre-training and then fine-tune the results using the small dataset.

I was thinking of freezing the encoder side of the transformer after the pre-training and letting the decoder part free to do the fine-tuning. How would one do this with OpenNMT-py?

Answer (score 1):

Please be more specific about your questions and show some code which will help you to get a productive response from the SO community.

If I were in your place and wanted to freeze a neural network component, I would simply do:

```
for name, param in self.encoder.named_parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

Here I assume you have a NN module like as follows.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, params):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = TransformerEncoder(num_layers,
                                        d_model, 
                                        heads, 
                                        d_ff, 
                                        dropout, 
                                        embeddings,
                                        max_relative_positions)

    def foward(self):
        # write your code
```

Comment: I'm using OpenNMT as a black box, following the documentation on http://opennmt.net/OpenNMT-py/. Unfortunately I don't know pytorch so I still didn't dig into the source code of the library. But with your answer might help me understand, thank you.